# Allocate people to teams based on 33/67% percentile of variable

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, quantile

I have a dataset where I would like to allocate people to different groups based on criteria, however, I would like R to do this automatically. I have separated my variables in <=.33 percentile and >=67 percetile and else.

```
dfOCEAN <-df[1:60,1:7]
print(colnames(dfOCEAN))
dfOCEAN <- dfOCEAN[complete.cases(dfOCEAN),]

i = 0
  for(i in 1:length(dfOCEAN$factor_e)){
    if(dfOCEAN$factor_e[i] <= quantile(dfOCEAN$factor_e, c(.33))){
      dfOCEAN$Introversion[i] <- 1
    }
    else if(dfOCEAN$factor_e[i] >= quantile(dfOCEAN$factor_e, c(.67))){
      dfOCEAN$Introversion[i] <- 2
    }
     else
     dfOCEAN$Introversion[i] <- 3
  }

i = 0
for(i in 1:length(dfOCEAN$factor_c)){
  if(dfOCEAN$factor_c[i] <=quantile(dfOCEAN$factor_c, c(.33))){
    dfOCEAN$Conscientious[i] <- 1
  }
  else if(dfOCEAN$factor_c[i] >= quantile(dfOCEAN$factor_c, c(.67))){
    dfOCEAN$Conscientious[i] <- 2
  }
  else
    dfOCEAN$Conscientious[i] <- 3
}
```

Then I am trying to create random samples with Dplyr's slice function.

```
dfOCEANset <- dfOCEAN %>% group_by(c(Introversion, Conscientious)) %>% slice(sample(c(1,2),1))
```

However, I am unable to get the desired results. Ideally, I would retrieve a dataframe whereby the data would be clustered with a combination of the different categories and the names would remain

Answer (score 3):

Try this loop-less (but untested in the absence of a reproducible example) method:

```
dfOCEAN$fac_grp <- c(1,3,2)[ findInterval( dfOCEAN$factor_e,
                           quantile( dfOCEAN$factor_e, c(0, .33, .67)), 
                               )}
```

R is intended to be used as a "vectorized" language and both the `findInterval` and `quantile` functions will return vectors, with `findInterval` giving a vector the same length as its first argument. You added a little wrinkle in asking us to arrange in a rather unnatural manner, which I handled by using the result from findInterval as an index into a three-item vector. The other function that does something similar (but returns a factor) is the cut function.

Comment: Hi 42, amazing answer, which really removes the need to actually loop, however, the latter part of the query, would like to automatically create teams out of people ranked high or low on the 2 factors. Would you have any idea?

Comment: I illustrated how to do it with `factor_e`. I don't understand the difficulty. Seems that it would be obvious how to do it for `factor_c`

Comment: Indeed, that part is successful, however now with the data frame, I would like to subset the data frame into smaller sections, such that each smaller data frame represents a team, where people who are ranked high on factro_e and facto_c are grouped together, and low factro_e and facto_c, etc. I suppose I could just subset the dataframe and then take random samples of these dataframes to make smaller teams.

Comment: If you now use `interaction(fac_grp_e, fac-grp_c)` you should be able to use the `split` function. AGAIN, your persistent failure to post code that creates a suitable basis for demonstration leaves you with the responsibility of  using such hints to build code. It is NOT the responsibility of respondent to make test cases.